# Marklogic to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, marklogic

Please can some one tell me what will be the equivalent Postgresql query for below marklogic cts query

```
cts:element-query( xs:QName('party'),  cts:query(search:parse( $text )) )
```

Note : Here 'party' is xml tag in document.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question if you don't show what the value of `$text` is. Not to mention that PostreSQL (SQL) vs. a MarkLogic cts query are really very different things. Are you trying to figure how to do the equivalent of a SQL LIKE query within a particular column in a PostrgreSQL table?

Comment: @MadsHansen yeah I am trying to figure out the equivalent SQL query . Text vale here is "law".